# Switching Screens with Try and Except statements Python Kivy Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, kivy, kivy-language

I am in the process of making a GUI for a web scraper that requires singing into a page (Selenium and Kivy). Sometimes it says to verify your account and in theory, if the selenium driver finds the element that is specifically on that page, it should switch screens (Try and Except). If it doesn't find the element, it should add an error message. This, however, doesn't switch screens, it stays on the first one. I've been troubleshooting this for a while now and I'm not sure what the problem is. When the Selenium driver finds the element, it runs the code in that try statement. If it doesn't, the error message doesn't get added.

Here is my python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.config import Config
import linkedenInfo
from linkedenInfo import *
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Fl = FloatLayout()

#---
class SignInScreen(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    pwd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def sign_in(self):

        user = UsDefined()

        errMsg = Label(text="Incorrect Username or Passoword!\nPlease Try again", size_hint=(.5, 0.05),
                       pos_hint={'top': 0.6, 'center_x': 0.5})
        try:
            user.sign_in(self.email.text, self.pwd.text)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-nav"]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/h1')
                LinkedInGui.screen_switch_one(None)

            except NoSuchElementException:
                self.email.text = ""
                self.pwd.text = ""
                Fl.add_widget(errMsg)
#----



class VerifScreen(Screen):
    verifInput = ObjectProperty(None)

class ScreenMang(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("appFormatting.kv")

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(VerifScreen(name="_VerifScreen_"))

class LinkedInGui(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    def screen_switch_one(self):
        print("Hello 2!")
        sm.current_screen = "_VerifScreen_"



    # run the App


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LinkedInGui().run()
```

Here is my KV file:

```
ScreenMang:
    SignInScreen:
    VerifScreen:


<SignInScreen>
    name: "Sign-In"

    email: userEmail
    pwd: password

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"LinkedIn Web-Scraper"
            size_hint:(.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint:{'top': 0.975, 'center_x': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: userEmail
            hint_text:"LinkedIn Email: "
            size_hint:(.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'y': .85}
            multiline:False

        TextInput:
            id: password
            hint_text:"LinkedIn Password: "
            size_hint:(.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'y': .8}
            multiline:False
            password:True

        Button:
            text:"Sign-In"
            size_hint:(.5, 0.1)
            pos_hint:{'top': 0.76, 'center_x': .5}
            on_release:
                root.sign_in()


<VerifScreen>
    name: "_VerifScreen_"

    verifInput: verifInput

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "An SMS text message was sent to your phone number.\nEnter the code below."
            size_hint: (.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.79, 'center_x': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: verifInput
            hint_text: "Verification Code"
            size_hint: (.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.73, 'center_x': 0.5}

        Button:
            text:"Verify"
            size_hint:(.5, 0.1)
            pos_hint:{'top': 0.6, 'center_x': .5}
#            on_release:
#                root.sign_in()
```

Here is my Selenium code:

```
class UsDefined():

    def sign_in(self, usname, pwd):
        url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%' \
              '2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fsearch%2Fresults%2Fpeople%2F%3Forigin%3DDISCOVER_FROM_' \
              'SEARCH_HOME&fromSignIn=true&trk=cold_join_sign_in'
        driver.get(url)
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(usname)
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(pwd) 
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    def verif_code(self, verifNum):
        verifText = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/h1').text
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input__phone_verification_pin"]').send_keys(verifNum)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input__phone_verification_pin"]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Why can't I switch screens through python code? I would write the try and except statements in the KV files but that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it without "NoSuchElementException"?

Just an "except:"

```
    try:
        user.sign_in(self.email.text, self.pwd.text)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-nav"]')
    except:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/h1')
            LinkedInGui.screen_switch_one(None)

        except:
            self.email.text = ""
            self.pwd.text = ""
            Fl.add_widget(errMsg)
```

Not the best way to do it, but you can isolate the error.

Comment: Its the same result unfortunately

Comment: Is it a problem with the KV file?